# Refresh token from API with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

Good morning, I have a REST API which needs a token to access it. I already manage to generate the token with Reactjs, but now I need it to refresh from time to time. For that, I need to store the token somehow, so I can fetch the API again. I was trying with local storage, but I didn't succeed. Any help?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            models: [],
            isLoaded: false
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {
    const email = myEmail;
    const pass = myPass;
    const url = url;

    fetch(url + '/api-token-auth/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: pass,
        })
    })/*, fetch(url + "/api-token-refresh/", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, body: JSON.stringify({
            token: token
        })
    })*/
    // <-- code for refreshing token, working on it

        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        })
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                token: json
            });

            let token = this.state.token;
            console.log('var token: ', token);

            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log('localStorage w token: ', token);
}`
```

Comment: Did this code cause any error?

Comment: Yes, the one that is commented, between /* */ @Abinthaha

Comment: Are you getting the token? I mean is it being consoled when setting value to localStorage?

Comment: there is error with your code. you mixed up async/sync token save

Comment: I get a token, now I need that token to fetch the api, to refresh it. @Abinthaha

Comment: I think I didn't understand @dbvt10

Comment: Good morning too! Although it's almost afternoon here ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution, I needed to store the token as a string with `JSON.stringify` and then, when I need to use it again, use `JSON.parse`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const email = myEmail;
    const pass = myPass;
    const url = url;

        fetch(url + '/api-token-auth/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }, body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: pass,
            })
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                token: json
            }, () => {
                let tokenJson = JSON.stringify(json);
                localStorage.setItem('token', tokenJson);
            });
        }).catch(error => console.error('erro:' + error));


        fetch(url + '/api-token-refresh/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }, body: (localStorage.getItem('token'))
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                token: json
            }, () => {
                let tokenJson = JSON.stringify(json);
                localStorage.setItem('token', tokenJson);
            });
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the error is in second promise handler .then.
**this.setState({}) is an asynchronous function** which means the state is being set after other instructions in your .then function are executed.

```
.then(json => {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            token: json
        });

        /*the above function is executed after below statements are executed beecause the nature of this.setState is asynchronous*/
        /*and that is why you must be getting an old or garbage value from this.state.token then in localStorage */

        let token = this.state.token;
        console.log('var token: ', token);

        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    })
```

To work this out : 
You can provide a callback function in this.setState **which is executed only after the state has been set** ! Hurrrrayyyy ! Like this :

```
.then(json => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, token: json }, () => {
          //this is the callback function
          //you should do tasks which depend on new state here
          let token = this.state.token;
          console.log('var token: ', token);
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        });
 })
```

[dbvt10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10054091/dbvt10) pointed the same thing in comments above.

You can read more about setState callback function on [this awesome article](https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c) by Medium.com.
^_^

Comment: did you try to console the json variable  @SofiaRibeiro ? what is in the res variable ?

Comment: The console.log "localStorage w token" in my code above returns [object Object]

Comment: try consoling the json variable and check for it's type by typeof operator.. if json is an object then your token must be in some of its property (if it's ever being sent from the api).

Comment: says undefined as soon as I try to console log it outside the .then function

Comment: its scope is restricted to that block only.. try consoling it in .then block itself..

Comment: But I don't understand, it isn't even storing the token. I have this: `console.log('token: ', this.state.token);
                    let token = this.state.token;
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);`. The console.log shows a token but when I save it in localStorage it gets Object Object

Comment: did you find the solution yet ?

Comment: what was the bug ?

Comment: I added and answer to the question explaining :)